# Creating specific front pages for departments

Tags: navigation

The Drupal 7 site I am working on has its own company front page, and there are a couple of branches of the company in different location. I want to add specific front pages with "about / contact us / other menus" for each of those departments/branches of the company that will be displayed when each of the branches is accessed.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to code, and you are familar with [context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module you can use this [Context Reaction Menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_reaction_menus).
Add new context with a URL as a condition, for example "department1/*" and as a reaction change the main menu, this will change in all pages that start with "deparmente1"

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need different menu on different pages?
First create different menus on Drupal backoffice, then check your template files on your theme folder and find where it prints the menu (usually page.tpl.php).
Get the nid (node ID, in Drupal 7 the easier way is with args) and place and if/else condition, then print the menu following [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1043018)